# Javascript REST API not processing correct values

Tags: javascript, api, rest, authentication

I have built a JavaScript Server Authentication API, but am facing some issues. When I pushed this POST request using Postman:

> http://localhost:3000/signup?firstName=my&secondName=Name&email=test@test.com&password=password

The router triggers this function:

```
app.post("/signup", Auth.userExist, function (req, res, next) {
     if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass email and password.'});
        } else {
            var newUser = new User({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lasttName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
            });
            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
            }
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
            });
        }
    });
```

The `please pass email and password` error is firing, I can't see why this would be happening?

Comment: try req.query this should check query string params

Comment: Did you do a `console.log(req)` and examine what's in there?  This is elementary debugging.  Also, are you running middleware that processes the query string?  node.js does not parse the query string automatically without the appropriate middleware to do it.

Comment: @user2950720 Do you mean like instead of my if (!req.body.email etc., I use `if {!req.query){` ? If so, that sill produces the same outcome

Comment: what is inside Auth.userExist

Comment: Well, you are POSTing the params as a query string. Try adding them to the body of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this I am able to get past the error as you are sending a query string you need to use `req.query`

PARAMS test@test.com, password

If you want to use `req.body` you need to send the parameters not in the query string but in the body of the request e.g

```
{
  "firstName": "my",
  "secondName": "Name",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

```js
app.post("/signup", function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.query.email || !req.query.password) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      msg: 'Please pass email and password.'
    });
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      firstName: req.query.firstName,
      lasttName: req.query.lastName,
      email: req.query.email,
      password: req.query.password
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          msg: 'Username already exists.'
        });
      }
      res.json({
        success: true,
        msg: 'Successful created new user.'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I am still having a few problems though, I would be really grateful if you got a chance to look over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985013/api-function-isnt-firing) question