# Using Custom Icons for HTML buttons

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app using IONIC 2, and have the following group of buttons. Three of them use the standard Ionicons resources. The third one however, uses a custom image of a key, but as you can see, it isn't scaled appropriately.

[image: Buttons]

Here is my code:

scss:

```
  .buttons .key { 
      background-color: #de574b;       
      transform:rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform:rotate(45deg); 
  }

  .ion-ios-key::before, .ion-md-key::before {
      max-height: 20px;
      align-content: center;
      vertical-align: center;
      content: url('../../img/Key.png');
    }
```

html:

```
 <div class="buttons">
      <button class="bluetooth">
        <ion-icon name="bluetooth"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button class="help">
        <ion-icon name="md-help"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button class="key">
        <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button class="new" (click)="newDevice()">
        <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </div>
```

My `max-height` property doesn't do anything, and nor does a height property. How can I style this icon to fit so that is looks like the other icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align-content` only works with `display: flex`,`flex-direction: column`, and `flex-flow: row wrap` (under specific circumstances).

Try:

```
.ion-ios-key, .ion-md-key {
      line-height: 20px;
      vertical-align: center;
      background: url('../../img/Key.png')no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
```

Remove:

```
.ion-ios-key::before, .ion-md-key::before {
      max-height: 20px;
      align-content: center;
      vertical-align: center;
      content: url('../../img/Key.png');
    }
```

[**`background-size: contain;`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) will center the image automatically and expand it enough to maintain it's aspect ratio (ie max width and height without deforming), plus no clipping like what you experience with the original code. If you are not satisfied with it's position, use [**`background-position: center`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) or [**`background-position: 45% 45%`**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)*

*45% 45% is just an arbitrary value used as an example.

Comment: Thanks! That's great, and how can I get the image to center in the circle, as it doesn't at the moment?

Comment: `background-size: contain;` will center the image automatically and expand it enough to maintain it's ratio (ie max width and height without deforming), plus no clipping like what you experience with the original code. If you are not satisfied with it's position, use `background-position: center` or `background-position: 45% 45%` I'll include references in the answer.